# PostgreSQL 9.3, запрос с группировкой, выбор максимума из группы.

Tags: group-by, postgresql, sql

Есть таблица с полями `url` и `created_at`.

В таблице есть множество записей с одинаковым `url`. Мне нужно получить записи со самым старшим `created_at`, для каждой группы с одинаковым `url`. Т.е., имея:

```
url         | created_at
------------------------
abc         |          1
abc         |          2
def         |          3
def         |          0
```

Получить:

```
url         | created_at
------------------------
abc         |          2
def         |          3
```

Пробовал сделать это так:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
GROUP BY url
HAVING created_at = MAX(created_at)
```

Получаю:

```
ERROR:  column "items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

---

Попробовал то же самое немного иначе:

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) AS last_created_At, *
FROM items
GROUP BY url
HAVING created_at = last_created_at
```

Получил:

```
ERROR:  column "last_created_at" does not exist
LINE 4: HAVING created_at = last_created_at`
```

Похоже, я неправильно понимаю, как работает `GROUP BY HAVING`. Как мне достичь желаемого?

**ДОБАВЛЕНО:** Достиг желаемого с помощью вложенного запроса, но вопрос остаётся открытым, как это сделать без него:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at)
                    FROM items AS t
                    WHERE t.url = items.url)
```

Comment: если память не отшибло, то так

    SELECT url, MAX(created_at)
    FROM items
    GROUP BY url

> ERROR:  column "last_created_at" does not exist

алиас задан с одной буквой в верхнем регистре

Comment: Кроме url и created_at, есть другие поля, мне нужен `SELECT *`. Если в твой запрос добавить `*`, то он будет возвращать ненужные мне записи, просто добавляя какой максимум, без фильтрации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот обсуждение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/276994
Если я правильно понял: нужен или вложенный запрос, или self-join.

Comment: Да, похоже, проще никак.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. `url` идентична, то нужно просто найти максимальный `created_at`:

```
SELECT url, MAX(created_at) as created_at
FROM items
GROUP BY url
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT url,created_at FROM items GROUP BY url ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.